# Why don't my two Classes interact with each other?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I'm new to Java, I'm trying to use threads to link two classes, a `Son` and a `Father`.
The problem is that when I run the `Father` class it doesn't communicate with the other one.

Heres is the code:

**Son:**

```
public class Mayusculas {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String cadena = reader.readLine();
    
        //Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    
        while (!cadena.equals("fin")){
            System.out.println(cadena.toUpperCase());
            cadena = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Father:**

```
public class Comunicacion {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        try {
            Process hijo = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "mayusculas.jar").start();
            System.out.println("Proceso Creado");
        
            BufferedReader entradaHijo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hijo.getInputStream()));
        
            PrintStream salidaHijo = new PrintStream(hijo.getOutputStream());
        
            BufferedReader entradaPadre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            line = entradaPadre.readLine();
            while ((line = entradaPadre.readLine()).compareTo("fin") != 0) {
                salidaHijo.println("");
                salidaHijo.flush();
                System.out.println("Mensaje enviado al proceso hijo");
                if ((line = entradaHijo.readLine())!=null){
                    System.out.println("Resultado del proceso hijo");
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Proceso finalizado");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Errero durante la ejecucion: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In particular, when I run my code, I get:

```
**Mensaje enviado al proceso hijo**
```

And it doesn't continue, with the results.

I've tried to solve this by looking all over Google but didn't find anything related to my problem.

Comment: Does your `Hijo` get every message that you type in, or does it stop printing it after the first time? Please be more specific and precise while describing your problem, since it's still not clear even after the edit. Also, telling us what you've tried by yourself would be useful to everyone who's willing to help you!

Comment: Sorry my english isn't good. I'll try my best: so, firstly when i type the word it doenst connect with Hijo, it prints again "proceso creado". Then I do everything, i clean and build, i copied and pasted mayusculas.jar in the folder DIST  of father's folder. I tried to write entradaHijo.readLine() before the loop. And still not connecting with the other class.

Comment: So I re-read your code now and noticed that you have two `main()` in two different classes. Please note that Java should have a single `main()` method declared just like you did in a Main class. Then, you can create your objects (`Father` and `Hijo`) there, assign them to two different processes and executing them.

Comment: I've found the problem but i dont know how to fix it: i need to write inputs from father to send to hijo, that print Multiplication table 1...10. I had 2 main because is diferrents projects but one has .jar and i connect it with tha class `process`  and ´processbuilder´